# Basic callback function result

Tags: javascript, callback

I am trying to understand the callback concept.

When I do that:

```
var myCallback = function(data) {
 console.log(  'got data: '+data);
};

var usingItNow = function(callback) {
  callback('get it?');
};

usingItNow(myCallback);
```

I get that as output as expected:

> got data: get it?

But when I do the below, I get `undefined` as output, why is that?

```
var myCallback = function(data) {
 return 'got data: '+data;
};

var usingItNow = function(callback) {
  callback('get it?');
};

console.log(usingItNow(myCallback));
```

Comment: Just look at `usingItNow` in isolation: what does it `return`? Nothing. Callbacks are pretty irrelevant to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return from the `usingItNow` as well.

```js
const myCallback = function(data) {
    return 'got data: '+ data;
};

const usingItNow = function(callback) {
    return callback('get it?');
};

console.log(usingItNow(myCallback));
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with callback. You are printing out the result of a function call, but the `usingItNow()` function doesn't return anything, so the result is `undefined`.

To prove that it has nothing to do with callback, try to print out the call to a standard function that returns nothing and you will get `undefined` too:

```js
function usingItNow(num) {
  num = num + num;
};

console.log(usingItNow(10));
```

Now, simply make the function return something and you will get it printed out:

```js
function usingItNow(num) {
  return num + num;
};

console.log(usingItNow(10));
```

Which leads to what Suren mentioned in his answer, return the result of the callback to get it printed out:

```js
const myCallback = function(data) {
  return 'got data: ' + data;
};

const usingItNow = function(callback) {
  return callback('get it?');
};

console.log(usingItNow(myCallback));
```

Comment: I would give correct answers to both but SO doesn't allow me so! Also can't upvote yet.

Comment: You'll be able to vote soon (you only need 15 rep), but don't worry about it, I answered in a hope it will benefit others, not to get votes. I just thought Suren's answer might not be detailed enough for some people.